# solana-validator performance drop with -account-index spl-token-owner,

Tags: validator

I'm doing some tests with solana-validator and when trying to enable the account indexing by spl-token-owner there's a significant performance drop, delaying the catch up by up to 100 slots. I'm a bit confused as using account index should in fact prevent such performance drops when having a lot of active accounts. Any clue of what could be the source of this behaviour? Running the validator without account indexing has no performance issues

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index is just for speeding up RPC’s getProgramAccount request.

It doesn’t help with performance and it will effect performance because every time the accounts are modified, it needs compute power to update the index as well.

If you want to use the index, you should upgrade the system memory and your CPU.

If your node are not used as RPC endpoints, I suggest you don’t use the account index.